# How to add leading zeroes and type mismatch for BAPI parameter POSEX

Tags: excel, vba, bapi

I am new to Excel VBA scripting to create sales order in SAP system via BAPI, below are the issue I am facing :

1. Picking Material number from the Excel cell and passing to the sales order BAPI.

   ```
    Dim Material As String
    Material = ActiveSheet.Range("E14")
    oItemsIn.Value(1, "MATERIAL") =  Material
   ```

   In this case the BAPI returns this error message:

   > Material 2094266 does not exist in sales area

   but if I pass material `"000000000002094266"` then it works fine.

   How I can change the format with leading zeroes in the material number after picking value from the cell?
2. How I can pass material config (variant config) for the line item I am passing below values?

   ```
        Set CFGS_REF = oBapiCtrl.DimAs(boOrder, "CreateFromData", "OrderCfgsRef")
        Set CFGS_VK = oBapiCtrl.DimAs(boOrder, "CreateFromData", "OrderCfgsInst")
        Set CFGS_VALUE = oBapiCtrl.DimAs(boOrder, "CreateFromData", "OrderCfgsValue")

        'OrderCfgsRefinst
        CFGS_REF.Value("POSEX") = "000010" 
        CFGS_REF.Value("CONFIG_ID") = "000010"
        CFGS_REF.Value("ROOT_ID") = "00000010"

        ' forOrderCfgsVk
        CFGS_VK.Value("CONFIG_ID") = "000010"
        CFGS_VK.Value("INST_ID") = "00000010"
        CFGS_VK.Value("CLASS_TYPE") = "300"

        'OrderCfgsValue

        CFGS_VALUE.Value("CONFIG_ID") = "000010"
        CFGS_VALUE.Value("INST_ID") = "00000010" ' Item
        CFGS_VALUE.Value("CHARC") = "PRG_ORD_SOURCE"
        CFGS_VALUE.Value("Value") = "Excel"
   ```

   But it throws this error at the line `CFGS_REF.Value("POSEX") = "000010"`:

   > type mismatch

Comment: One question per question, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the leading zeroes back to your material number:

```
oItemsIn.Value(1, "MATERIAL") =  Format(Material, "000000000000000000")
```